# Icon in bootstrap 4 inside the input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking for a solution to create and input like this one in bootstrap 4
[image: Desired target]

I am using font awesome and this is the code that I use

```
<div class="input-group">
    <label class="control-label">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" />
    <span>
        <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

but i get the image out of the input
Any help  please
https://jsfiddle.net/5db2ho62/

Comment: Create a fiddle. I can edit that

Comment: can you describe what you're trying to achieve?  the image you provided doesn't load (also, for future generation's sake you shouldn't rely on images in SO)

Comment: @SyamPillai SO has [built-in snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) now; there's no reason to link outside the site in this instance

Comment: The `span` tag should have the class `input-group-addon`. Then overwrite the style with CSS. Make sure the span line is above the input line

Comment: Can you provide your custom CSS additions as well? They may be interfering with Bootstrap

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5db2ho62/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need to have the icon inside the input- you can place it next to the input field, and remove the input field's border using CSS.

HTML:

```
<div class="input-group">
<i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name Here" >
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input{
  border:none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

input:focus,
select:focus,
textarea:focus,
button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.fa-user-circle-o{
  color: gray;
}
```

Updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/5db2ho62/2/

Comment: but i need it to have a border like the image above

Comment: @MohamedSherifNoureldin You can add a border to the outer div, it would look the same- updated fiddle

Comment: This answer is not great. UX would expect clicking anywhere in the bordered area to select the input to start editing. Input should hold the border, and have padding for the icon to be positioned within, such that a click on the icon also selects the input.

Answer (score 23):

here is the solution

```css
span{
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
input{
  padding-left: 25px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="input-group">
  <span>
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" />
</div>
```

here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5db2ho62/4/)

Answer (score 21):

```css
.main {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

.form-group .form-control {
    padding-left: 2.375rem;
}

.form-group .form-control-icon {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    width: 2.375rem;
    height: 2.375rem;
    line-height: 2.375rem;
    text-align: center;
    pointer-events: none;
    color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<link id="bootstrap-css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="main">
  <div class="form-group">
    <span class="fa fa-search form-control-icon"></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
  </div>  
</div>
```

Try it!

Comment: Great solution, I'm not sure how it works so well, but it works! If someone wants to have this icon on the right side of the input, then `right: 0;` will work. And remember to remove not needed padding on the left.
This should be on the very top, since it allows to click in the input through the icon.

Answer (score 12):

This method seems to be the cleanest. You do not need to add any custom CSS. You can do the following all with Bootstrap:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.input-focus').on('click', function() {
    $(this).children('input').focus();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="input-group input-focus">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text bg-white"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
  </div>
  <input type="search" placeholder="Search" class="form-control border-left-0">
</div>
```

See the bootstrap 4 documentation for more details on how you can manipulate the placement and styling of the input icon:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/

**UPDATE**:
I added a small jQuery snippet to focus the input when the search icon is clicked, per a suggestion to this answer in the comments. The JavaScript snippet and jQuery library script inclusion are not requirements for the icon to appear and work properly, but they do help with UX.

Comment: The downside with this approach is the selected state of the input does not cover the entire "apparent" element. My expectation would be that the icon is contained inside the input, such that a click on the icon also clicks the search field.

Comment: @mix3d I agree with the downside you mentioned and think it is better UX to have the icon focus the input. This is easily achieved with a small bit of JavaScript. I've added an update to the answer.

Comment: But the focus state still doesn't cover the entire "field". Visually, the icon is "inside" the input field, and as such, I would expect the focus state to include the icon's area

Comment: I see your point, however it doesn't bother me, or affect how I would use the input. I added my answer to emphasize that the desired icon can be achieved without any custom CSS. I understand there are other ways to achieve the same with custom CSS.

Comment: By far the best answer.  People have to nit pick everything, even though it is the best!

Answer (score 7):

The solution is maybe to use unicode in placeholder.
Here the cheatsheet for all font awesome unicode http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/

```css
input {
  padding:10px;
  font-family: FontAwesome, "Open Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group">
  <label class="control-label">Username</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="&#xf075; Username" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the following code no CSS required.

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center small">
    <i class="fa fa-search fa-fw text-muted position-absolute pl-3"></i>
    <input type="text" class="form-control py-4" placeholder="Search..." style="padding-left: 38px;"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Very short and useful.

Answer (score 5):

Tested with Bootstrap 4.

Take a `form-control`, and add `is-valid` to its class. Notice how the control turns green, but more importantly, notice the checkmark icon on the right of the control? This is what we want!

Example:

```css
.my-icon {
    padding-right: calc(1.5em + .75rem);
    background-image: url('https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/svgs/regular/calendar-alt.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right calc(.375em + .1875rem);
    background-size: calc(.75em + .375rem) calc(.75em + .375rem);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <input type="text" id="date" class="form-control my-icon" placeholder="Select...">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```html
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js " integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo " crossorigin="anonymous "></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js " integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49 " crossorigin="anonymous "></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js " integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em " crossorigin="anonymous "></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!--Font Awesome (added because you use icons in your prepend/append)-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<body>
  <div class="col-sm-4 input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <div class="input-group-text">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is a great answer for bootstrap 4! Using this one now.

Answer (score 1):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.input-container {
  display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.icon {
  padding: 10px;
  background: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  min-width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.input-field {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: none;
}

.input-field:focus {
  border: 2px solid dodgerblue;
}

/* Set a style for the submit button */
.btn {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.btn:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php" style="max-width:500px;margin:auto">
  <h2>Register Form</h2>
  <div class="input-container">
    <i class="fa fa-user icon"></i>
    <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="usrnm">
  </div>

  <div class="input-container">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope icon"></i>
    <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">
  </div>

  <div class="input-container">
    <i class="fa fa-key icon"></i>
    <input class="input-field" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="psw">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn">Register</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

see [bootstrap From](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_form_icon)

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to type custom CSS code. Works great on Bootstrap 5. Don't forget to add font-awesome.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

...

<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-text fa fa-user-circle-o form-control-icon"></span>
  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Putting the icon inside the text area isn't a nice solution to this. The best way is to create a simple workaround. So first we'll create a form with the icon before the input field like below:

```css
input {
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
}

input:focus,
select:focus,
textarea:focus,
button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="input-group">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your name" >
</div>
```

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bmv3r9dp/3/)

Next up with some styling we'll make some changes so that it looks like it's one `input` field:

```css
input {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.fa-user {
  padding: 10px;
}

.input-group {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 250px;
}

input:focus,
select:focus,
textarea:focus,
button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div class="input-group">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your name" >
</div>
```

see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bmv3r9dp/5/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: And where is the icon?

Answer (score -1):

**Here is the easiest method**

```html
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js " integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo " crossorigin="anonymous "></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js " integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49 " crossorigin="anonymous "></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js " integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em " crossorigin="anonymous "></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!--Font Awesome (added because you use icons in your prepend/append)-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<body>
  <div class="col-sm-4 input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <div class="input-group-text" style="border-right:none;background:transparent">
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="border-left:none">
  </div>
</body>
```